# remove hiddenfield value using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have set value in hidden field like: D1|12345;D2|34567;

i need to remove value D1\12345; from hidden field using jquery.

can anyone suggest me how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// creat an array from field value, like array('D1|12345','D2|34567')
var field_value_array = $('#field_id').val().split(';');

// write only the second element
$('#field_id').val(field_value_array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

eg:

```
var newVal = $('#hiddenInput').val().replace('regex or string here','');
$('#hiddenInput').val(newVal);
```